# How to set gameobject tag to null?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a trigger box using colliders to disable a script. The thing is it works perfectly but when using `OnTriggerExit` I'm unsure how to paraphrase from sending Enemy Tag to `null`.

```
public Casting stop;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}


private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        Debug.Log ("is working trigger");
        stop.GetComponent<Casting> ().enabled = false;
    }

}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag != "Enemy")
    {
        Debug.Log ("is ended trigger");
        stop.GetComponent<Casting> ().enabled = true;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you want to set GameObject's tag to null?

Comment: I want that when the gameobject Enemy is setactive = false the script Casting will be active

Comment: `if (other.gameObject.tag != "Enemy")` Uh...that means that if the player casts a spell, then walks through the trigger volume and leaves, the spell ends. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: What I am trying to do is have the object walk through the trigger box which would disable a script. When the object is no longer present or null the script is active. writing the line ` (other.gameObject.tag != "enemy")` seemed like the best choice.

Comment: I found the issue `stop.GetComponent<Casting>.enabled = true;` should be `stop.GetComponent<Casting> ().enabled = !stop.enabled;`